# Reading data into SAS

Tags: sas

I am using SAS via my school's citrix server. That may or may not make a difference. Here is my code which is typed from Chapter 3 of Learning SAS by Example:

```
data demographics;
infile 'D:\mydata.txt':
input Gender $ Age Height Weight;
run;
```

It keeps giving me an error that the physical file doesn't exist. I downloaded the data in a zip file and extracted everything. I put it on my flash drive which is what I'm trying to read it from. What could possibly cause this? Disclaimer: I am new to SAS.

Comment: You need to talk to our site admin.  It's very possible that Citrix cannot see your d:\ depending on how you're connected. I don't think this is a SAS issue, though.

Comment: Instead of D:\, try \\client\d$\

Comment: This isn't a SAS issue, it's a computer setup limitation. Your schools server can't see your USB because that's in your desktop. You likely have some assigned space you can upload files to, possible a university shared space or even on your SAS server. Check your instructions, I'd be surprised if they hadn't given you some way of dealing with this issue because it will come up for everyone quickly.